# Get highest value of a column in a stored procedure in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in SQL Server

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('kii.p_CreateSection') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE kii.p_CreateSection
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE kii.p_CreateSection
    @Name AS NVARCHAR(200),
    @DocumentId AS INT,
    @TypeId AS INT = NULL,
    @ReportId AS INT = NULL,
    @OrdinalPosition AS SMALLINT
AS
    INSERT INTO kii.Section (Name, DocumentId, TypeId, ReportId, OrdinalPosition)
    VALUES (@Name, @DocumentId, @TypeId, @ReportId, @OrdinalPosition)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO

GRANT EXECUTE on kii.p_CreateSection TO p_role_kii
GO
```

The table `Section` is related to `Document`. Each document has several sections and they're ordered by the `OrdinalPosistion` value.

I'd like to test that if the given value for `@OrdinalPosition` is 0, then set it at the maximum value of all the sections of this Document +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert kii.Section( Name, DocumentId, TypeId, ReportId, OrdinalPosition )
Select @Name, @DocumentId, @TypeId, @ReportId
    , Case
        When @OrdinalPosition <> 0 Then @OrdinalPosition
        Else    (
                Select Max( OrdinalPosition ) + 1
                From kii.Section
                Where DocumentId = @DocumentId
                )
        End
```

Comment: I think after the FROM line, you need to add `WHERE DocumentID = @DocumentID`

Comment: This fails when there are no sections already in the table. Use this Coalesce(Max( OrdinalPosition )+1,1 ) to get the value for OrdinalPosition